# Change window manager in Fedora 18

Tags: fedora, window-manager, settings

Fedora 17 would let me choose my window manager on login; now with Fedora 18 not only can I not choose it on login, but I can't find a way to change it anywhere.

Is there a way to easily switch between window managers in Fedora 18?

Comment: In my experience, Fedora offers the desktop environment on login only if you have several installed. Which ones do you have?

Comment: @vonbrand: I have the default window manager, plus xmonad -- which is the exact setup I had with Fedora 17.

Comment: I don't use Fedora but Debian but it should be the same. I run the desired WM by putting the appropriate command in `~/.xinitrc` - `openbox`, for example. So it runs when X starts.